# How to fix react Hook useEffect has missing dependencies

Tags: reactjs

I have researched a little bit about this eslint error and have tried to implement the solutions explained in a few post. But actually they made things worse. Because, if I would accept having the warning in the console, my application then seems to work. As soon as I implement one of the suggested solutions, the app fails with errors telling me there is a problem with too many renders.

Basically, I have a list with regions and cities that are using "useState".
When the page displays, I want to set a region as selected. And as the cities are a part of the region-variable, I also display the cities connected to the selected region. To make this happen, I am using useEffect. More or less in this way:

```
    const [regions, setRegions] = useState(
        {
            region: 'region1', id: 1, cities: {name: 'city1', id: 1}
            ,region: 'region2', id: 2, cities: {name: 'city2', id: 1}
        }
    );
    const updateCityList = () => {
        let found = regions.find(el => el.className === 'selectedRow');
        setCities(found.cities);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const newArr = [...regions];
        newArr.find(el => el._id === 1).className = 'selectedRow';
        setRegions(newArr);
        updateCityList();
    }, []);
```

Now, in the console I see the warning:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'regions' and 'updateCityList'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Putting the functions inside the useEffect's array, will cause the error with rerender.
I also have tried using "useCallback". But I got similar errors.
The warning does not seem to be suppressed using the "ignore next line". However, I would prefer to solve this warning rather then trying to hide a possible issue.

Comment: Add `[cities, regions]` as the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In this useEffect:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const newArr = [...regions];
        newArr.find(el => el._id === 1).className = 'selectedRow';
        setRegions(newArr);
        updateCityList();
    }, []);
```

You should add a flag to check if the effect has already ran once (return immediately if so), so the effect won't update regions state again causing infinite rendering.

Something like:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!flag)
            flag = true;
        else
            return;
        <Your logic>
    }
```